# get nearest latitude and longitude

Tags: php, sql, google-maps, haversine

I have latitude and longitude in this format : 
  15.1393658,76.92150059999994,13.0873783,77.41112120000003,14.7017498,77.59016529999997

If I enter the another Latitude and longitude like lat=13.0874193,lan=77.41100640000002 they has to give nearest lat lan of above lat lan.
I have used Haversine Formula,
$connection = Yii::$app->getDb();

```
    $command = $connection->createCommand('
        SELECT fpro_userid, 6371 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(('.$user_lat.' - abs('.$new_string.')) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS('.$user_lan.' * pi()/180 ) * COS( abs('.$new_string.') * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(('.$user_lan.' - '.$new_string.') * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance FROM farm_profile having distance < 19.2 ORDER BY distance
    ');  

    $result = $command->queryAll();
```

in php but not working.
So please anyone help to solve this problem

Comment: Please tell us what error you actually get. "Not working" won't help us.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to translate the distance into degrees of longitude and latitude, filter based on those to bound the entries that are roughly in the bounding box, then do a more precise distance filter. Here is great paper that explains how to do all this:
    http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

Comment: why? @Deep 3015

Comment: this [explanations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7521) . If you ever post jsfiddle link in the answer, then alert is generated which says to add relevant code in answer . So here add  **link** but also add some of the code which is essential. So that it is preserved for future readers external links is unpredictable. I hope you understand